# Is it possible to set symbol layers always on top?

Tags: qgis, symbology, layers

Is it possible to set symbols always on top, also if the layer with the symbol is drawn under another layer?

Example:
My layer order is like that:

Streets (top)
Buildings
Landuse (bottom)

The Buildings layer have centroid-symbols. But these are drawn underneath the streets layers:

[image]

Comment: Why cant your building layer be on top in the TOC?

Comment: In my case, the buildings layer have to be under the streets layer for several reasons. I cant change the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either

1. duplicate the buildings layer, once on the bottom for the polygon, one on top for the symbol, or
2. create symbol labels. Labels are always on top. See `Labels | Background | Shape = SVG`

Comment: What do you mean with symbol labels? Labels drawn as symbols? How to do so?